# Convert SQL XML results of multiple rows into a single well-formed XML document

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, xslt

I need to print the library elements in Indonesia that carries a qty of >10 books from XML datatype.

**XML**

```
</libraries>
  <library>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>DabZ</name>
    <address>
      <street>Green</street>
      <city>Patemon</city>
      <country>Indonesia</country>
    </address>
    <books>
      <book>
        <id>2</id>
        <im_id>00851287</im_id>
        <name>Alice in wonderland</name>
        <price>80.22</price>
        <qty>10</qty>
      </book>
      <book>
        <id>11</id>
        <im_id>50241141</im_id>
        <name>Master your mind</name>
        <price>75.03</price>
        <qty>84</qty>
      </book>
    </books>
  </library>
  <library>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Skippad</name>
    <address>
      <street>Harper</street>
      <city>Makale</city>
      <country>Indonesia</country>
    </address>
    <books>
      <book>
        <id>2</id>
        <im_id>00851287</im_id>
        <name>Alice in Wonderland</name>
        <price>80.22</price>
        <qty>4</qty>
      </book>
      <book>
        <id>15</id>
        <im_id>67510150</im_id>
        <name>Flu Relief</name>
        <price>92.26</price>
        <qty>361</qty>
      </book>
      <book>
```

**My attempt in SQL**

I managed to filter the results for the library elements, however, it is not well-formed. If anyone could help, i will greatly appreciate it.

```
SELECT library 
FROM library_multirow
WHERE XMLEXISTS ('/descendant::library[child::address/child::country="Indonesia" and sum(child::items/child::item/child::qty)>10]' PASSING library);
```

**Result in SQL**

```
<library><id>....
<library><id>...
```

**Desired Output**

```
<libraries><library><id>.....<library><id>
```

Comment: Do you want to construct a string/text with the XML? Or another SQL XML value?